# Prompt user to save their changes made in salesforce before leaving that screen

Tags: salesforce

if in salesforce we make changes in one screen and without saving them moves to another screen, a popup message is shown.
how to implement that in another screens.[About this Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBdvc.png)

Comment: You probably mean https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event ? Which technology, Visualforce/aura/lwc, what have you tried so far?

Comment: not this unload_event